# Python: How to reduce memory loss while compiling high numbers of images...

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I have been trying to create just shy of 2000 images using a netCDF file for Arctic Sea Ice concentrations. Just when I think it is working, I realize it is eating up so much memory that it either creeps along, or just fails. 
So far, I have tried clearing all the variables within my -for- loop, and I have tried to use the plt.close(fig) and plt.close('all'). None of which helped.

Reaching out now...Does anyone have any other suggestions I could try? 
I need to be able to save each image in the file.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

## Read in netCDF file.  NOTE: Change format if it does not read.
NH_Ice=nc.Dataset('Oc-Tech/Final_Project/ncFiles/NH_SeaIce.nc', 'r')

## Save netCDF parameters into arrays.
lons = NH_Ice.variables['longitude'][:]
lats = NH_Ice.variables['latitude'][:]
time = NH_Ice.variables['time'][:]
time_units = NH_Ice.variables['time'].units

## Calculate Date from given data file
dbase= '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
db=datetime.datetime.strptime(dbase, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
start=db+datetime.timedelta(days=time[0])
end=db+datetime.timedelta(days=time[-1])

#print fh.time_strlen
si = NH_Ice.variables['seaice_conc'][:]
NH_Ice.close()

m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=45,lon_0=-156,resolution='c')   

#total time steps
tts=1980
for ti in range(0,tts):

    fig = None
    lat = None
    lon = None
    xi = None
    yi = None
    sip = None

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    m.drawcoastlines(color='black')
    m.fillcontinents(color='limegreen',lake_color='blue')
    m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,20.)) 
    m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.))
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='darkblue')

    lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) #sea ice
    xi, yi = m(lon, lat)

    sip=(si[ti])  ## Plot u data from a particular day

    m.pcolor(xi,yi,np.squeeze(sip))     
    plt.savefig("fig"+str(ti)+".png")
    #plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Maybe it's the basemap object `m` that needs all that memory? Why are you doing all those operations on `m` inside the loop? Can't you do everything from `m.drawcoastlines` to `m.drawmapboundry` before the for loop?

Comment: If you need to do all those modifications to `m` inside the loop, you should probably also create a new `m` for each iteration of the loop. I'm not familiar with this library, but it looks like you are abusing that poor Basemap object by applying new layers of meridians and squiggles over and over.

Comment: I recommend having a read on https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-profile-memory-usage-in-python to learn how to measure memory usage in parts of your code. This should help, as it would be hard for anyone to know where's the problem just by inspecting the code.

Comment: Thank you! I will read through that blog and then see how things go. 
As you can probably tell, I am pretty new to Python.
Though I am actually kicking myself for spacing on the other m modifications. >__<